# Why is the null coalescing operator breaking my string assignment in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a query string in a web form, and I'm dealing with values from the parameters that might be null. There are lots of ways to check and fix these, but the most elegant one I found is the following:

```
string pass;
pass = "BillabilityDetail.aspx?_startDate=" + _startDate.Text + "&_endDate=" + _endDate.Text + 
       "&_isContractor=" + _isContractor.SelectedValue + "&_busUnit=" + _busUnit.Text 
       + "&_projectUnit=" + _projectUnit.SelectedValue + "&_leadCon=" + _leadCon.Value ?? -1
       + "&_acctExec=" + _acctExec.Value ?? -1 + "&_isBillable=" + _isBillable.SelectedValue + 
       "&_isActive=" + _isActive.SelectedValue + "&_include=" + _include.SelectedValue;
```

The only issue is... it doesn't work. When the code reaches this part,

```
"&_leadCon=" + _leadCon.Value ?? -1 + "&_acctExec=" + _acctExec.Value ?? -1
```

the string stops assigning values. So the string would end with &_leadCon=.
I know of ways to work around this, but I don't know why it stopped working in the first place. Any tips?

Comment: shouldn't -1 be a string? e.g. "-1"

Comment: May I suggest you considering using `string.Format`, or a `StringBuilder` object?

Comment: what is exactly the type of leadcon?

Comment: I would second the suggestion to use `string.Format`, as it will make the end result much more readable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `+` has higher precedence than `??`, thus you need to surround your null-coalescing expressions in parenthesis.

```
"&_leadCon=" + (_leadCon.Value ?? -1) + "&_acctExec=" + (_acctExec.Value ?? -1 )
```

[See the precedence chart here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly that it was such a small thing. I guess this is why you don't code on four hours of sleep! :P

Comment: @proseidon: No worries, it's often the little things that bite us, especially with lack of sleep thrown in the mix :-)

Answer (score 11):

Try using parentheses to tell the compiler exactly what you mean.

For example:

```
"&_leadCon=" + (_leadCon.Value ?? -1) + "&_acctExec=" + (_acctExec.Value ?? -1)
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to look this up but I can't find `??` in the operator precedence chart! (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323.aspx)

Comment: @James That'd be why, then :) I saw the chart in your answer had `??' in.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add braces i.e.

```
"&_leadCon=" + (_leadCon.Value ?? -1) + "&_acctExec=" + (_acctExec.Value ?? -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [precedence of operators in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) ([more up to date but slightly less helpful version here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)), then you can see `+` comes above `??`.

This means you are actually asking for most of your statement after `??` to be treated as one block.

So,

```
string test = "hello" + value ?? "this is" + " a test"
```

actually means:

Add `"hello"`, then add `"this is" + " a test"` if `value` is null, otherwise add `value` itself.

So you probably want brackets in there as other answers said. I just thought I'd try and explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

There are more issues than you think:

1. As you said, it does not work
2. There are about 20 string creations (srting is immutable, `string` + `string` creates  a new string and copies the contents of strings into it, so it's *lot* of memory copying). Hovewer, C# compiler makes an optimization for you, so this time you are lucky.
3. It barely readable

Consider using [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.string.format.aspx) method.

```
string urlTemplate = 'BillabilityDetail.aspx?_startDate={0}&_endDate={1}';
pass = String.Format(urlTemplatel, _startDate.Text, _endDate.Text);
```

Also, as others pointed out, there are operator preceence errors (`+` has higher precedence than `??`), but this approach is free of it, as those coalescing operators will reside in parameter construction.

Comment: Actually, multiple chained concatenations on the same line don't create all the extra temporary strings, .NET optimizes those into an underlying `StringBuilder`.  For more info, I have a post on `+` vs `Format()` vs `StringBuilder` http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2010/05/10/c-string-compares-and-concatenations.aspx

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare thank you for the point. I've performed quick test, it appears that `String.Format("{0} - {1} = {2}","1", "2", "3")` is about as twice slower as `"1" + " - " + "2" + " = " + "3"`

Comment: It's actually a fairly common misconception.  It probably was an issue at one time in the begining, but the .NET compiler writers optimized it for us :-)

Comment: @J0HN in your second example, the compiler optimizes it to a single string literal: `"1 - 2 = 3"`.  If you declared `string one = "1";`, etc., then used those, you might have a better comparison.